# FileNotFoundException when trying to read assets with Roboelectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to run a test that needs access to a file in the assets folder using roboelectric 3.3.2 with

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application.getAssets().open("my_file");
```

but I always get this error

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/intermediates/bundles/debug/assets/my_file (No such file or directory)`

The thing I really fail to understand is that even if I specify a path for the assets dir this way

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23, assetDir = "/home/")
```

I still get the same error, I mean the error with the same path `build/intermediates...` so, the assetDir value is being ignored? Or am I missing something here?

Is it possible to open a file from the assets folder without too much hassle?

**EDIT**

as suggested I tried copying assets file to test/resources folder but I'm still getting the same error, still the same FileNotFoundException with  build/itermediates.. path

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        String sharedTestJavaDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'

        test {
            java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
            resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Roboletric wont be able to read actual device assert folder so you have to virtually define some location and dump your resources to that path as below code :

For robolectric you have to define assert path as below :

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        String sharedTestJavaDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'

        test {
            java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
            resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Access fixture files from your androidTest env this way:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

Comment: #Ref : https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2065#issuecomment-148128155

Comment: wait a sec, you mean that even if I copy the file in that resources folder, I still cant use context.getAssets.open?

Comment: yep since it will pick ur resources from `['src/test/resources']` if configured

Comment: I configured the sourcesets but I'm still getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/intermediates/bundles/debug/assets/ also, why is @Config(assetDir="..") being ignored?

Answer (score 2):

for `Roboelectric` to work just like android device put this in build.gradle

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      includeAndroidResources = true
    }
  }
}
```